# What's the point of migration column options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to understand why Rails chooses to include **:limit**, **:null**, **:default** and others in its migrations column options.

It's my understanding that Rails is opinionated against DB constraints, rather enforcing consistency and non-nullness (and many others) through ActiveRecord validations such as **validates_presence_of** and various callbacks such as **before_save**.

Assuming hypothetically that I fully subscribe to the "everything in the model" philosophy, shouldn't I avoid using those abovementioned column options? What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Default values are useful to set at a db level, otherwise you're going to have code everywhere to ensure booleans are set to false by default instead of nil.

Comment: indeed. also, just because a db is created using a rails migration, doesn't necessarily mean its the only application using it.
There's also a performance element in the db setting the default rather than the app processing it.